# Similar items in two arrays

Tags: php, arrays

Consider two following arrays as examples:

```
$a1=['It is a book.','I like Mongo','Hello World!'];
$a2=['I like MongoDB','Bye World!','It is a book.','I am Here!'];
```

Each array item is a sentence. $a2 is a modified version of $a1. I want to find corresponding version of each $a2 item in $a1 (if any). How can I do that in an efficient way?

```
function foo($firstArray,$modifiedArray){
 // ???
}
```

desired result: (it shows status of each item in the second array)

```
[
0=>['modified',1], //First item in second array is modification of the second item of first array.
1=>['new'],
2=>['intact',0],
3=>['new']
]
```

I want apply this on a huge database and performance is critical for me.

Indeed I want trace sentences of Wikipedia articles among revisions.

Comment: If performance is critical, why do you use PHP?

Comment: You say you want to apply this on a huge DB (btw: what is huge?), and that performance is critical. What queries are used to get this data? What are the table schema's? It's far more likely you'll be able to get (close to) your desired result using specific queries then you are using PHP alone...

Comment: I don't understand this question at all.  The desired result seems so alien from the given arrays.

Comment: @bozdoz The question is updated.

Comment: @EliasVanOotegem Indeed I want trace sentences of Wikipedia articles among revisions.

Comment: @PHPst: Instead of computing the difference between each revision on the spot, I'd strongly recommend storing _only_ the current version of an article/page, and store the change-log (sort of like Git does: safe the diffs, not the files)

Comment: @EliasVanOotegem Actually I am going to do taht, I tried to keep the question as simple as possible.

Comment: I think you need a lot of granulation here. I think you might need to use REGEX here, and/or levenshtein, but they could be resource expensive calculations and unaccurate. By granulation I mean how mean how many or what percentage would mean one element is a variation of another, etc.

Comment: @aleation Actually the sentences are long enough to find out their novelty our modifications.